# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat' has no attribute 'v2' For Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm working on Tensorflow Object Detection API on Python. I'm training a custom object detection algorithm and the pretrained model which is been used is ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config when I try to run train.py from the legacy folder from Models/object_detection i get this particular error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 48, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Users\Captain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 47, in <module>
    from object_detection.models.ssd_mobilenet_edgetpu_feature_extractor import SSDMobileNetEdgeTPUFeatureExtractor
  File "C:\Users\Captain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\models\ssd_mobilenet_edgetpu_feature_extractor.py", line 19, in <module>
    from object_detection.models import ssd_mobilenet_v3_feature_extractor
  File "C:\Users\Captain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\models\ssd_mobilenet_v3_feature_extractor.py", line 25, in <module>
    from nets.mobilenet import mobilenet
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\Captain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\slim-0.1-py3.6.egg\nets\mobilenet\mobilenet.py", line 399, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat' has no attribute 'v2'
```

I have

1. Tensorflow 1.13.2
2. Python 3.6
3. Windows 10

This is the command I'm trying to run on windows command prompt.

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=Users/Captain/Desktop/ANPR V1/ --pipeline_config_path=Users/Captain/Desktop/ANPR V1/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config
```

I thought it might be because I was using another model so also tried this command

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=Users/Captain/Desktop/ANPR V1/ --pipeline_config_path=Users/Captain/Desktop/ANPR V1/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

but I got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem. If you downloaded the latest repository of [tensorflow models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) then try downloading this [**tensorflow models of version 1.13.0**](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/archive/v1.13.0.zip) instead the latest repo as you are using Tensorflow 1.13.2. **It solved my problem.**